# Android Studio 2.0 with Gradle 2.0 and Dexguard bootClasspath error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dexguard, bootclasspath

I updated to Android Studio 2.0, and now I would like to build my project, but I got this exception:

> Execution failed for task ':app:dexguardDebug'.
>   No such property: bootClasspath for class: com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder

I use dexguard, gradle 2.0.0

I don't know what is wrong with the new Android Studio.

Comment: I use gradle 2.0.0: you mean the android gradle plugin? or really gradle (whose current version is 2.12)?

Comment: I use android gradle plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I checked DexGuard 7.1.22 which gradle plugin is supported, and i saw that Android gradle plugin 1.5.0 version is supported, so I changed from 2.0.0 to 1.5.0 and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The error is thrown because the bootClasspath property was replaced by the method getBootClasspath at some point ([source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/master/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/AndroidBuilder.java#174)).

In my case the error was caused by an outdated plugin: gradle-android-scala-plugin. If you're also using that plugin, then it should help if you update the Gradle dependency to the android-plugin-1.5.0 branch. This branch is not on Maven at this time, so I had to use [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/) to specify the git branch. The top half of my project Gradle file now looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.github.saturday06:gradle-android-scala-plugin:android-plugin-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
```

If it's another plugin causing the error, you can find the stacktrace in (Android Studio installation)\system\log\idea.log (in my case  C:\Users\Andre\.AndroidStudio2.0\system\log\idea.log). My stacktrace looks like this:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: bootClasspath for class: com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder
    at jp.leafytree.gradle.AndroidScalaPlugin.addAndroidScalaCompileTask(AndroidScalaPlugin.groovy:211)
etc
```